# Hide react-select menu with CSS

Tags: reactjs, react-select

When react-select's menu is closed, it is removed from the browser dom. I have faced the situation where menu must not be removed from the dom. Is it possible to hide it without removing from the browser dom, for example set "display: none"?

Comment: it seems like you have answered your own question, so why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: You should copy the source code and and change the hiding logic and create your own react-select.

Comment: This is just a guess but do you want to hide it when the menu is closed?

Comment: This is the problem - I do not know how to implement the logic of hiding menu with CSS. And yes, I want to hide it when menu is closed.

Comment: Any advice is welcome.